# Sql DISTINCT remove column from result

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have simple PostgreSQL query, that do query events by recent date, but 
I wanted to remove this Distinct column(time) from result

```
SELECT DISTINCT time, sensor_id, event_type, value from events ORDER BY sensor_id

+---------------------+---+---+-----+
| 2014-02-13 12:42:00 | 2 | 2 |   5 |
| 2014-02-13 13:19:57 | 2 | 4 | -42 |
| 2014-02-13 13:32:36 | 2 | 3 |  54 |
| 2014-02-13 14:48:30 | 2 | 2 |   2 |
| 2014-02-13 12:54:39 | 3 | 2 |   7 |
+---------------------+---+---+-----+
```

need result like this

```
+---+---+-----+
| 2 | 2 |   5 |
| 2 | 4 | -42 |
| 2 | 2 |   2 |
| 2 | 3 |  54 |
| 3 | 2 |   7 |
+---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like:

```
SELECT sensor_id, event_type, value 
from   (
          SELECT DISTINCT time, sensor_id, event_type, value from events
       ) A 
ORDER BY sensor_id
```

Comment: this sql code does nt order results by recent date.

Comment: @Swapnil, that's right, that was not a requirement, and wasn't sorted that way in the original query. Furthermore, it's not possible, you can't sort on something you don't have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PostgreSQL [`DISTINCT ON (...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) feature:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (time, sensor_id, event_type, value)
       sensor_id, event_type, value from events
ORDER BY sensor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate function to order by max value of time.

```
SELECT  sensor_id, event_type, value
FROM events 
GROUP BY sensor_id, event_type, value
ORDER BY MAX(time) DESC
```

Comment: i need to query latest events by 'time' colummn

Comment: @ZarahDewayne this sql ensures that distinct values are selected without including time in the output. Inline queries won't work in this case as they don't guarantee that records in the outer query are in expected order.

Answer (score 0):

USE [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) and rank [window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) function

```
  with temp as
    ( select time,sensor_id, event_type, value , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY     ensor_id, event_type, value order by 'time') as rnk
       )
       select time,sensor_id, event_type, value from temp  where rnk =1
```